# In elixir REPL (in emacs shell) how to change yellow to black?

Tags: elixir

How do I get control over the elixir REPL?

It gives me yellow on white which I cannot see.

I am running it inside of an emacs shell which I assume is a common use-case?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable coloring with:

```
IEx.configure([colors: [enabled: false]])
```

Or tune them separately [following the docs](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/iex/IEx.html). To make this permanent, you can create `.iex.exs` also described on the same site with docs.